# jquery accordion click twice on the same title

Tags: jquery, accordion

i want to build an accordion effect, and I´ve reached an good result but when i click on the same botton again the pictur won´t change until i click on an other title...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.boxes').slideToggle("fast");
item = "";
item0 = "";

$(function () {
    $('.box_head').click(function () {
        idelem = $(this).attr('id');
        idelemdiv = idelem.replace('boxhead_', 'box_');

        if (item === idelemdiv){
            $('#' + idelemdiv).slideToggle("normal");
            item = "";

        } else {
            $('#' + item).slideToggle("normal");
            $('#' + idelemdiv).slideToggle("normal");
            $('#' + item0).children('img').attr({
            src: 'http://wp.wicker-schuetz.de/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/images/buttons/bg-open.png'
        });
            item = idelemdiv;
            item0 = idelem;
        }

        if ($('#' + idelem).children('img').attr({
            src: 'http://wp.wicker-schuetz.de/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/images/buttons/bg-open.png'
            })) {$('#' + idelem).children('img').attr({
            src: 'http://wp.wicker-schuetz.de/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/images/buttons/bg-close.png'
            });}
        });
    });
});
```

## jsfiddle

where is my fold?

In the end i think it needs an else arguement but my try wont work.

Comment: Do you have an element with `.box_head` class containing another element with this class?

Comment: What's that last if block supposed to do?

Comment: It seems like you're overdoing this. Maybe try and manipulate these pictures with CSS classes instead of JS (just add the class to the container with JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This always returns true:

```
 if ($('#' + idelem).children('img').attr({
        src: 'http://wp.wicker-schuetz.de/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/images/buttons/bg-open.png'
        }))
```

If you change it to be something like this, you may get the results you are looking for:

```
if ($('#' + idelem).children('img').attr('src') = 'http://wp.wicker-schuetz.de/wp-content/themes/Drlawyer/images/buttons/bg-open.png')
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zDpgQ/5/

Comment: this work's great until i use the IE. There I get the Failure: SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
function item() {
    [native code]
}

Comment: If you change "item = "";" to "var item="";" the issue will go away. (http://jsfiddle.net/zDpgQ/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the whole thing easier like so:

## Example

```
$(function() {
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $(document).on('click', '.box_head', function(e) {
        var head = $(this),
            icon = head.children('img'),
            box = head.next('.boxes');
        box.siblings('.boxes:visible').slideUp('normal', function(e) {
            $(this).prev('.box_head').children('img').prop('src', icon.prop('src').replace('bg-close', 'bg-open'));
        });
        box.slideToggle('normal', function(e) {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                icon.prop('src', icon.prop('src').replace('bg-open', 'bg-close'));
            }
            else {
                icon.prop('src', icon.prop('src').replace('bg-close', 'bg-open'));
            }
        })
    });
});
```

### Fun version of Example!